# Best fit in logarithmic chart

Tags: logarithms, interpolation

I have several variances ($\sigma^2$) which value depends on the velocity ($v$). As you can see in the graph, if increase the velocity, the variance does the same.

I am studying this dependency, but I do not know the exponent of the velocity. I have tried to write:

$$\sigma^2=q \cdot v^m$$

where, $q$ is a constant, and $m$ the exponent that I have to find.

I have rewritten this equation in logarithmic format:

$$\log(\sigma^2)=m \log(v)+\log(q)$$

now is a straight line equation.

I am looking for $m$ and $\log(q)$, via best fit. I am not a mathematician, I am an engineer, so I can use the tool for best fit, but this tool does work not as I would like.

**Question: there is a way to compute the best fit in a logaritm chart, with strait line (first order) and know its slope ($m$) and y-intercept ($\log(q)$)?**

Thank you and by,
Giacomo

[image: Three variances vs. velocity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an equation of the type $\sigma^2 = q \cdot v^m$, which, in the logarithmic chart must be:

$$\log(\sigma^2)=m \log(v)+\log(q)$$

So, I have computed the $\log(\sigma^2)$ for each variance, and $\log(v)$ for each velocity (mine $y$ and $x$).

At this point, I have computed their best fit, looking $\log(\sigma^2)=m \log(v)+\log(q)$ like $y=mx+q$, so looking for a linear interpolation.

We can call $\hat{m}$ the best fit of $m$, and $\log(\hat{q})$ the best fit of $\log(q)$.

Eventually, my best fit equation is:

$$\hat{\sigma^2} = e^{\log(\hat{q})} \cdot v^\hat{m}=\hat{q}\cdot v^\hat{m}$$